# Split json data into multile json data using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, split

I have **variable data** having json data as below:

```
{  
   "label":["ch1","ch2","ch3"],  
   "data": [  
             [-0.001000, -0.562500, 0.001875, 0.002188],  
             [-0.000998, -0.687500, 0.000937, 0.001875]  
           ]   
}
```

What I want to split above json data using jquery and get them stored in three **variables data1, data2, data3** having json data as below:

```
{  
   "label":["ch1"],  
   "data": [  
             [-0.001000, -0.562500],  
             [-0.000998, -0.687500]  
           ]  
}
```

and

```
{  
    "label":["ch2"],  
    "data": [  
                [-0.001000, 0.001875],  
                [-0.000998, 0.000937]  
            ]  
}
```

and

```
{  
   "label":["ch3"],  
   "data": [  
             [-0.001000, 0.002188],  
             [-0.000998, 0.001875]  
           ]  
}
```

Kindly tell me how to split common json data into three different json data as above using jquery?

Comment: Why insist on using jQuery?  It is not some be-all, do everything, don't have to write any javascript yourself API!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirements are vague, but this is what I think you mean:

```
var main = {  
   "label":["ch1","ch2","ch3"],  
   "data": [  
             [-0.001000, -0.562500, 0.001875, 0.002188],  
             [-0.000998, -0.687500, 0.000937, 0.001875]  
           ]   
}

for (var i in main.label) {
  var k = +i + 1, // make k a 1-based value
  data = [];

  for (var j = 0; i < 2; ++j) {
      data.push([main.data[j][0], main.data[j][k]);
  }

  window['data' + k] = {
    "label": [ main.label[i] ],
    "data": data
  }
}

console.log(data1, data2, data3);
```

Comment: fine!! but what if i want something like
      [main.data[j][0], main.data[j][k]]
using another loop for j variable dynamically